# Understanding adventureworks2012 db structure

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I go through a tutorial on `hierachyid` and for their explanation they use the following query on the `advantureworks2012`

```
Select * From HumanRessources.Employee
```

I generated the diagram and can find a table called employee but no HumanRessources one. [image].

I tried to find a documentation of the `AW2012 db` but could only find one of the `AW2008` which does not have `HumanRessources`.

My question: What is HumanRessources, since it is not a table I do not understand what it is and how this is implemented?

Comment: Looks like the schema is called 'HumanResources' this is in place of the usual 'dbo'

Comment: It is the SCHEMA.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HumanResources` is indeed the schema, with `Employee` being the table name.

You would therefore query the table using `SELECT * FROM HumanResources.Employee;`

You might find the official data dictionary useful here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124438(v=sql.100).aspx

Alternatively, see the following diagram for an overview of the AdventureWorks2008 database ( it's almost identical to 2012). Notice the shaded areas represent the different schemas.

[image: Adventureworks2008 ER Diagram]